# My problem with the velocity of the object with position $z=t^2-t^3$.

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics, special-relativity

[image]

(a)[image]

(b)Using first derivative test, $$\frac{dz}{dt}=0.$$ We get $t=2/3$. When $t=2/3$ object move $z=4/27$ units far from $z=0$.

(c) Velocity at which object departed from $z=0,$ $$\frac{dz}{dt}|_{t=0}=0.$$ Am I correct? What about the velocity at which it return? Is it $$\frac{dz}{dt}|_{t=1}?$$

(d)Is $z=f(t)$ unique?

May I know where is my mistake? Please help me to complete the answer.

Comment: Why do you think that you made a mistake?

Comment: velocity at which object return. Am I using the correct formula?

Comment: Yes, you are. As for part (d), the solution is not unique, as you say. The question only asks you to find one example. Can you find it on your own?

Comment: okay. Then I got the complete solution. Thank you very much sobi :)

Comment: The title may be edited. It does not provide much information about your question ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are OK so far and your graph works for the first 3 parts of the problem.

For part $(d)$ they want to find a different function with both velocities being zero at $t=0$ and $t=1$

You consider a polynomial in form of $bt^2+ct^3$ and find the coefficients.
It should work out.